# Propagate the status from Table A to Table B to Table C in notion?

Tags: notion

I am trying to create a template where I have the following 3 table:

- BookDB
- ChapterDB
- SectionDB

In **SectionDB** I have 3 columns: *Name*, *Status (of type Status)*, *Chapter (related to Name column of ChapterDB)*.
[image]

In **ChapterDB** I have 3 columns: *Name, Book (related to Name column of BookDB), Sections (related to Name column of SectionDB)*
[image]

In **BookDB** I have 3 columns: *Name, Chapters (related to Name column of ChapterDB), Status (which must get the status/progress from the Status column of ChapterDB)*
[image]

Now I can create a column by the name: *Status (of type Rollup)* in **ChapterDB**, which can then present the progress of a chapter based on the combined value of Status column for all the sections of a Chapter (related column in **SectionDB**) of **SectionDB**. So, this is one-level relation and is achievable.

**Question: What I want, is to use this Status (in ChapterDB) to present status/progress of the Book in BookDB. How can it be done?**

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a rollup of a rollup directly, you have to make a formula property in the chapter database and have if display the rollup of the status: `Prop(rollupofstatus)` then you can do a rollup of that property on the book database.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Nickmeu was hard information for me to find so I thought I'd reinforce and elaborate. I hope others find this helpful.

**If you're rolling up a text field, a formula works just fine.**

Let's say that you have *tableOrdersCompany1* and *tableOrdersCompany2*, each with the following columns:

1. *Name* (text)
2. *orderID* (text)

If you make *tableOrdersCombined* the following way, it will output text in Col6:

1. *Name* (text)
2. *name.company1* (relation)
3. *name.company2* (relation)
4. *orderID.company1* (rollup)
5. *orderID.company2* (rollup)
6. *form.orderID.combined* (formula)
   `concat(prop("orderID.company1"),prop("orderID.company2"))`

**The problem is when you try to rollup *relation* or *rollup* fields. For example:**

Let's say that you have *tableOrdersCompany1* and *tableOrdersCompany2*, each with the following columns:

1. *Name* (text)
2. *orderID* (relation)

If you make *tableOrdersCombined* the following way, it will output a *link* in Col6:

1. *Name* (text)
2. *name.company1* (relation)
3. *name.company2* (relation)
4. *orderID.company1* (rollup)
5. *orderID.company2* (rollup)
6. *form.orderID.combined* (formula)
   `concat(prop("orderID.company1"),prop("orderID.company2"))`

**Instead, make *tableOrdersCompany1* and *tableOrdersCompany2*, each with the following columns:**

1. *Name* (text)
2. *orderID* (relation)
3. *form.orderID* (formula) `prop("orderID")`

Then, if you make *tableOrdersCombined* the following way, it will output text in Col6 (although 4 & 5 will be text also):

1. *Name* (text)
2. *name.company1* (relation)
3. *name.company2* (relation)
4. *form.orderID.company1* (rollup)
5. *form.orderID.company2* (rollup)
6. *form.orderID.combined* (formula)
   `concat(prop("orderID.company1"),prop("orderID.company2"))`